# Correspondence between two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S be a subspace of V. Prove that the function that assigns to each subspace T ($S \subseteq T \subseteq V$) the subspace T/S of V/S is bijective.

Edit: I actually meant bijective, not only injective. What about the surjectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T_1,T_2$ be two vector spaces with $T_1/S =T_2/S$.

Let $t_1 \in T_1$ then $t_1+S\in T_1/S=T_2/S$, hence there is $t_2 \in T_2$ such that $t_1+S= t_2+S$ which implies that $t_1-t_2 \in S$ so $t_1-t_2=s$ for some $s\in S$; thus $t_1=t_2+s \in T_2$, i.e. $T_1 \subseteq T_2$. In the same way you can show that $T_2 \subseteq T_1$.

**Edit**

To show that your map is surjective, Let $W \subseteq V/S$ a vector space; and define $T= \{v \in V|v+S \in W\}$, and prove that $T$ is vector space and $f(T)=W$.

Comment: Amazingly, we came up with the same notation (it's not suprising that we came up with the same proof).

Comment: The main difference is that you talk and write a lot :D

Comment: Thank you guys for the proof. But I made a typo in the original statement. I actually meant bijective, and I'm having difficulties proving surjectivity. Can you help me?

Comment: see the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Given a space $V$, let $\mathsf{Sub}(V)$ be the set of its subspaces. Let $f : \mathsf{Sub}(V) \to \mathsf{V/S}$ be the map which assigns to each subspace $T \in \mathsf{Sub}(V)$ the subspace $T/S \in \mathsf{Sub}(S/V)$,
$$f(T) = T/S.$$
(Next time when you ask a question introduce the notation that you want us to use, or else we will come up with our own.) Recall that an element of a quotient space $T/S$ is written as $x + S$ where $x \in T$ and that $x + S = y + S$ is equivalent to $x - y \in S$.

Suppose now that $S \subseteq T_1 \subseteq V$ and $S \subseteq T_2 \subseteq V$ are two subspaces and that $f(T_1) = f(T_2)$, that is $T_1/S = T_2/S$. We need to show that $T_1 = T_2$, and we do so by proving $T_1 \subseteq T_2$ and $T_2 \subseteq T_1$. Given any $x \in T_1$, we have $x + S \in T_1/S = T_2/S$, therefore there exists $y \in T_2$ such that $x + S = y + S$, from which it follows that $x = y + s$ for some $s \in S$. But since $S \subseteq T_2$ we now see that $x$ is a sum of two vectors in $T_2$, therefore $x \in T_2$. We have shown that $T_1 \subseteq T_2$, and the proof that $T_2 \subseteq T_1$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the quotient map $\pi : V\rightarrow V/S$. The idea is to show that this sets up a bijection between subspaces $T$ such that $S\subset T\subset V$ and subspaces of $V/S$. As a hint on how to proceed, the map $\pi$ above acts on subspaces by:

If $T\subset V$ is a subspace, then $\pi(T)$ is a subspace of $V/S$.

If $T'\subset V/S$ is a subspace, then the preimage $\pi^{-1}(T')\subset V$ is a subspace containing S (though one should check this).

Now can you show that these induce a bijection?